# how to create dropdown list for year in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am quite new to .net mvc i have to generate the drop-down for year with key value pair.
I tried by following way

in my model

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> GetAllYears()
        {
            for (int i = 2012; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, i);
            }
        }
```

and in my view as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, new SelectList(Model.GetAllYears(), "Key", "Value", Model.Year))
```

Here dropdown is generate but with empty values. is am i missing there?

Comment: Your code does not enter your for loop. You need to correct for loop

Comment: can you suggest me any other way for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
 for (int i = 2012; i <= 3; i++)
```

2012 is already larger than 3.